# MITMPROXY - Changing URL of captured request and replaying it

Tags: mitmproxy

I have searched on the web to do this, but have only found "modify JSON", "modify response" but was wondering whether this is actually possible.

If mitmproxy captures https://example.com/user/ and gets a response of JSON data, is it possible to replay the GET with a different /user/ in the URL?
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the response, you can modify the `request` URL before it hits the server. A no-code way is to use the [map remote](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/overview-features/#map-remote) option, alternatively you can write a small addon that uses the [`request` hook](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/dev/api/events.html#HTTPEvents.request).